# How to model LCGA with time-varying covariate

Tags: time-varying-covariate, latent-class, growth-mixture-model

We have the following data set that contains: 
Variable $X$ - measures a proportion of young employees in an organization
Variable $Y$-  measures a proportion of young managers in the same organization
$X$ and $Y$ are measured at 4 time points, 3 years apart. 
These variables are curvilinearly related to each other at each time point.

1. We would like to test an LCGA model identifying class trajectories
   in X (including a quadratic term) and use Y at Time 1 as a covariate.
   Such a model will test whether management at Time 1 predicts employee class trajectories.

   Is this approach appropriate or we have to include Y as a time-varying
   covariate, as it correlates with X at each time point?
2. is there a way to include a time-invariant covariate Z
   (dichotomous) that is expected to moderate the above-mentioned class
   trajectories?

Comment: I am using Mplus

Comment: ¿Are you set on using an SEM-based framework to address this problem? (As opposed to a mixed effects model.)

Comment: @ Gregg H: Thank you! This is exactly what I did- switched to mixed effects modelling and then to a GEE model as results look similar and the GEE is much simpler to run and write-up. However, I am still wondering about the use of a variable as a TVC and TIC: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341972/including-the-same-variable-as-a-time-varying-and-time-invariant-covariate-in-ml